# Are there any to-scale diagrams of the TRAPPIST-1 system

Tags: trappist-1

I was recently told that the planets in TRAPPIST-1 are close enough together that you can see them from each other, as visible, discernible planets "hanging in the sky". i.e. much like the moon.

I'm trying to understand the implications of the claim, and started by trying to find a to-scale diagram of some, or all, of the TRAPPIST-1 system. Showing the start, the planets, their sizes and orbits.

I couldn't find such a diagram. Does one exist?